# Can I overload the << operator in a base class here?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

So I'm looking to create a series of classes that are derived from a base class, and each class implements the virtual method `std::string toString() const`. Am I able to implement an overload for the << operator in the base class like so?

```
    class BaseDataType
    {
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BaseDataType* obj)
        {
            os << obj->toString();
            return os;
        }

     .... rest of class
```

My problem lies in specifying the input type of `obj`. At the moment, I'm implementing the overload in each derived class, and specifying the input type.

Can I specify the overload in the base class, and if so, how?

Comment: When you tried, what went wrong ?

Comment: You pretty much have your own answer right in the question, except I'd recommend a reference rather than a pointer. Why isn't it working for you?

Comment: A more canonical form here is `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BaseDataType& obj);` taking the object by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it nearly right. The one problem is that you should not use the pointer as argument of `operator<<`, because those operators normally use reference:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BaseDataType& obj)
{
  os << obj.toString();
```

Then all you need to do it to provide the virtual `toString` method in derived classes - the `operator<<` in the base class will call them.